# How can I hide volume control in Gnome-shell?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, system-tray

This is my system-tray.

[image: This is my system-tray.]

I'm looking to hide the volume control.

What do you suggest then? Should I use the terminal?

Comment: whats the Ububtu version??

Answer (score 4):

***OS: Ubuntu 18.04***

***Edit on 23rd Apr 2020***

You may Install the extension. https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/Hide-Volume-Indicators

---

Previous Answer.

run the below command to hide the Volume Indicator..

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._volume.indicators.hide()'
```

[image]

to bring back the volume Indicator... run the below command.

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._volume.indicators.show()'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107140/discussion-on-answer-by-pratap-how-can-i-hide-volume-control-in-gnome-shell).